# How to programatically click all buttons on a page with similar class and add delay

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

So I have a web page with around 20 buttons on it and I want to click all of them through the console of Google Chrome.

The classes of the buttons are all the same; however, a lot of other non button elements also have the same class.

How can I *only* click the buttons with the same class (for example: randomclass) and add a 1 second delay between each click.

I started off with:

```
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("randomclass");
```

Now when I look at that array, I not only get buttons but also links with that same class which I don't want to click.

After that I'm typing in:

```
for(var i=0; i<elems.length;i++) { elems[i].click(); }
```

What this is doing is clicking all of the elements inside the array. How to tell it to only look at buttons (

Thanks guys. Interested in seeing what's the solution for this.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

Comment: You mention that you are looking for a delay.. is that a way of saying that you want to *throttle* your callback so that you can only click on one button of all the buttons at most, once per second?

Comment: Please take a look at [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e55h1hp1/1/). It uses `querySelectorAll` to get a reference to the wanted buttons, and shows how to convert the returned collection to array. Then it iterates through the array using `forEach`, and creates a function, which is executed with a delay, for every button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an `if` statement to clarify that simple requirment:

```
for(var i=0; i<elems.length;i++) {
    if( elems[i].tagName.toLowerCase() === "button" )
        elems[i].click();
}
```

In the future, or with more complex filters, you can use [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) method to get your nodes.

```
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('button.randomclass');
for( var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++ ) {
    //Do stuff here...
}
```

Comment: Care to explain the downvotes? Does this solution does not answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

this solutions is jQuery based. :)

```js
$('.clickme').each(function(i,button){
   $(button).click(function(e){
      console.log('im on fire ',$(this).attr('name'));
   });
});

$('#fire').click(function(){
   console.log('fired');
   $('.clickme').each(function(i,button){
      $(button).trigger('click');
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='button' id='fire' value='FIRE BOTH' />
<input type='button' name='one' class='clickme' value='One' />
<input type='button' name='two' class='clickme' value='Two' />
```

Comment: Don't forget to mention that you're introducing [jQuery](https://jquery.com) into the mix!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
var elems = document.querySelectorAll("button.randomclass");
function runClick(){
  if(elems.length){
    elems[0].click(); //<= you can use jquery click event => $(elems[0]).click()
    elems.splice(0, 1);
    setTimeout(function(){
      runClick();
    }, 1000);
  }
}

runClick();
```

Answer (score -1):

First, just get the buttons with Document.querySelectorAll and go from there.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll